# Firestore - How to get ID of a Document from Collection? Android Java

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a firestore collections "Usuarios", in this collections have a lot Documents, each Documents is a one user from my app, i need add more fields on the specific document, but, the Id of document is different that my (CurrentUser.getUUid());.

See here:

[image: Here]

What I need is to write several more fields (dynamically) to a logged in user document, but currentUser.getUid returns a document field, not the document ID itself. Que seria o necessário para gravar naquele documento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was use other method to add documents to collection and the uuid from getCurrent user is already the id of document, i do not know if it is correct (for security), but, was my solution...